# How to detect windows 32bit or 64 bit using NSIS script?

Tags: nsis

I have written nsis script for java project.I have Batch file in my project.I have written batch file for commonly windows 32bit and 64 bit.After installing i have started batch file automatically using **Exec** command.Its woks fine in 32bit windows.but the same time this is not worked well in 64 bit.so i suspect that before installing  i should check whether windows is 32 bit or 64 bit version.please share your views how to check?

Comment: Not worded as a duplicate question, but its the same: [use-one-nsis-installer-to-install-32-bit-binaries-on-32-bit-os-and-64-bit-binari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126629/use-one-nsis-installer-to-install-32-bit-binaries-on-32-bit-os-and-64-bit-binari)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the RunningX64 macro in the [x64.nsh](https://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/code/HEAD/tree/NSIS/trunk/Include/x64.nsh) header:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include x64.nsh

Section
${If} ${RunningX64}
    DetailPrint "64-bit Windows"
${Else}
    DetailPrint "32-bit Windows"
${EndIf}  
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks.In that url said ; File some.dll # extracts to C:\Windows\System32. what is some.dll? which file it mean to?. i could not able to understand

Comment: oh thanks.that {If} part where am i put in my script? .oninit()? or some other place?

Answer (score 65):

For future lazy googlers - A small snippet:

Include this:

```
!include x64.nsh
```

And use this if:

```
${If} ${RunningX64}
    # 64 bit code
${Else}
    # 32 bit code
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Does this detect all 64-bit architectures or just windows xp x64?

Comment: I couldn't find a definite answer, I always assumed it does! I've tested it on Windows 7 64bit and Windows XP 64 bit and it worked. I never had any trouble with it on any Windows platform

Comment: It applies to all 64-bit versions of Windows. (It calls IsWow64Process internally)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I use most of the time without the need for x64.nsh

```
Var Bit
System::Call "kernel32::GetCurrentProcess()i.s"
System::Call "kernel32::IsWow64Process(is,*i.r0)"
StrCmpS $0 0 +3
StrCpy $Bit 64
Goto +2
StrCpy $Bit 32
```

Now $Bit holds either 64 or 32 which can be used like this:

```
${If} $Bit == 64
     ...64-bit code..
${Else}
     ..32-bit code...
${EndIf}
```

Or

```
StrCmpS $Bit 64 SixtyFour ThirtyTwo

SixtyFour:
    ...
    Goto End
ThirtyTwo:
    ...
End:
```

I used `StrCmpS` as I believe it's a hair faster. Lol. Hope this helps! =)