# NSIS If Else statement with x64 header throwing macro error

Tags: 64-bit, nsis

when I was looking for an answer to how to find out if a Windows OS was 32bit or 64bit, I stumbled upon this other answer: [Use NSIS to install 32bit...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11127544/2009612) and used this code below.

```
!include x64.nsh

Function .onInit
    #Determine the bitness of the OS and enable the correct section
    ${If} ${RunningX64}
        SectionSetFlags ${SEC0000}  ${SECTION_OFF}
        SectionSetFlags ${SEC0001}  ${SF_SELECTED}
    ${Else}
        SectionSetFlags ${SEC0001}  ${SECTION_OFF}
        SectionSetFlags ${SEC0000}  ${SF_SELECTED}
    ${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

However, I run into this error:

```
!insertmacro: If
!insertmacro: macro named "_LOGICLIB_TEMP" not found!
Error in macro _RunningX64 on macroline 1
Error in macro If on macroline 5
```

I'm not sure what that's all about. I figured it might have been something to do with LogicLib.nsh, but I am using the exact same if, else statements else where in the same script and no issues there. So, it leads me to believe that its the [x64.nsh](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/x64.nsh) library that is stopping me.

Comment: Which NSIS version is this?

Comment: I was using 2.9, then I upgraded to 3.0. Got the error in both, but it was a problem with the library file I had. I needed this one, http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Include/LogicLib.nsh , the other lib file I had was completely wrong.

Comment: 2.9 was released in 2005 and did not have a x64.nsh!

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this error before. Your current code should work unless you happen to define LOGICLIB somewhere in your code before you include x64.nsh and/or LogicLib.nsh.

Try putting this at the top of your .nsi:

```
!ifdef LOGICLIB
!warning "LOGICLIB should not be defined here"
!undef LOGICLIB
!endif
!include LogicLib.nsh
!ifmacrondef _LOGICLIB_TEMP
!error "Corrupted LogicLib.nsh?"
!endif
!include x64.nsh
```

Comment: I got through this problem. What it was, is that I had a Library named hte same thing as I needed called LogicLib.nsh that was being called by x64 already. So, a friend of mine and I went looking for the correct one, and found it. Thank you for your help.